# How do I use td function for all column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to use the `td function` from the `tempdisagg()`. I have a dataset called `df` and would apply this function to my 3 columns.My datasets are in quarterly format and I wish to use the `td` function to change them to monthly.

Ihave seen the td function used: `td (monthly, denton-cholette)`. I am wondering if `td` can handle dataframes.

```
> dput(df)
  structure(list(Date = structure(c(951868800, 959817600, 967766400, 
  975628800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), x = c(2, 
  3, 12, 1), y = c(2, 4, 5, 1), z = c(5, 1, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



     Date                    x     y     z

     2000-03-01 00:00:00     2     2     5
     2000-06-01 00:00:00     3     4     1
     2000-09-01 00:00:00    12     5     2
     2000-12-01 00:00:00     1     1     4
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the code you want to use for `td`? What do the x, y, and z columns represent?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to try to understand how the td function works? For example, I looked over and saw that she works with time series. It's possible

```
  library(lubridate)
  z1 = ts(df$x)
  z2 = ts(month(df$Date))
  mod1 = td(z1 ~ z2)
```

And use an apply to iterate through the columns.

```
apply(subset(df, select = -Date), 2, function(x){
   z1 = ts(x)
   z2 = ts(month(df$Date))
   mod1 = td(z1 ~ z2)
   return(mod1)
})
```